# Dynamically define javascript class

Tags: javascript

I have a class defined as following

```
const CONST_VALUES = {
  '2times': 2,
  '3times': 3
}
export default class MyClass {
  constructor (value) {
    this.value = value
  }
  getValue (time) {
    return this.value * CONST_VALUES[time]
  }
}
```

I would like the `CONST_VALUES` beeing parameters loaded from the database. How can I instantiate a dynamic class that can be built from anywhere in my app using values from the database ?
I could add a setting from the class, but this require to provide settings to all instance at building.

Comment: Not sure I see how this requires a dynamic class. Load parameters from the database and then, in your class, refer to that object instead of this constant.

Comment: I wanted to avoid to provide the settings to all built object.

Comment: The OP might come up with some more specific code like showing what e.g. two distinct but CONST_VALUES depended class implementations are supposed to look like.